# inverse image of a family of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Les $X$, $Y$, $S$ be noetherian schemes, $f:Y\to X$ a morphism and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf on $X\times S$, flat on $S$. Is it true that

1. $(f\times I_S)^*\mathcal{F}$ is flat on S
2. for every closed point $s\in S$, $[(f\times I_S)^*\mathcal{F}]_s=f^*(\mathcal{F}_s)$

Answer (score 2):

1. No. For instance, let $S = \mathbb{A}^1$, $X = \mathbb{A}^1$, $Y = \{0\}$ is the origin of $X$, $f$ is the embedding, and $\mathcal{F}$ is the structure sheaf of the diagonal
   $$
   \Delta = \{(x,y) \mid x = y\} \in \mathbb{A}^2 = X \times S.
   $$
2. Yes, because the square formed by $Y \times \{s\}$, $Y \times S$, $X \times \{s\}$ and $X \times S$ is commutative.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are there simple hypotheses for 1. to be true ? For example $f$ is surjective ? Or $\mathcal{F}$ (or the $\mathcal{F}_s$) torsion free ?

Comment: I don't think a simple condition exists.